# Call to a member function count() on null (View: (Laravel 4.2)

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know how can to resolve this problem, I need to count the books by the domaine. Example:

> domaine #Science(10 books)

These my code :

```
<tbody>

<?php $book = Book::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get(); ?>

@if(count($book) >= 1)  

    @foreach($domaines as $domaine)
        <tr class="tr-body">
            <td>{{ $domaine->name }}</td>
            <td>
                ({{ $domaine->book->count() }})
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ URL::current() . '?id=' . $domaine->id }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-edit large"></i></a>
                <a onclick="return confirm('{{ Lang::get($path.'.delete') }}')" href="{{ URL::route('domaine_delete', $domaine->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                <i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach 

@endif

</tbody>
```

MODEL :

```
    Domaine model : <?php class Domaine extends Eloquent { protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at']; protected $table = 'domaines'; public function books() { return $this->hasMany('book'); } } 

Book model : <?php class Book extends Eloquent { protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at']; protected $table = 'books'; }
```

[image: expected result in the view image]

Comment: Show us how you define the relationship between Book and Domaine in your models

Comment: aboth not same table, but i create a liaison with them, 
Table : domaine (id, name, slug) and book : (id, title, author, date, location, domaine_id,...)

Comment: Ok, I can understand that they don't have the same table. What I mean is the models... I can see that you have a Book model, since you do `Book::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get()`, that's why I ask you for the relatioship between Book and the model that corresponds to the table where are the domaines. You can find the models at your project `/app` folder typically.

Comment: This is domaine model :  <?php

class Domaine extends Eloquent {
 
 protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at'];

 protected $table = 'domaines';

 public function books()
 {
  return $this->hasMany('book');
 }

}


Book model : 

<?php

class Book extends Eloquent {
 
 protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at'];

 protected $table = 'books';

}

Comment: Note that the relationship in your Damaine model is called `books`, but in the view you are using book `$domaine->book->count()`, so just changing it to `$domaine->books->count()` in your view should show you the related books count.

Comment: Do not put code in comments. Edit your question to include this information.